# Predicting The Next Term of a Sequence of Fractions

Tags: functions

I'm trying to predict the next term of the following sequence and possibly find its generating function,

{-2250/10000, -600/10000, 200/10000, 500/10000, 374/10000, -300/10000, -583/10000, -500/10000, -90/10000, 694/10000}  ,

when I use SequencePredict I get the wrong prediction. Is there a better way of doing this or is my sequence unpredictable?

Comment: Maybe it needs more terms to reproduce what you are thinking of.

Comment: It would be better to do a `Fit` I think : ```fit = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x];
Plot[fit, {x, 1, Length@data}, Epilog -> Point@Transpose@{Range@Length@data, data}]```

Comment: Where does this come from? If you multiply by 10000 you get an integer sequence. There is a great library for integer sequences called: OEIS  (online encyclopedia of integer sequences). As this sequence can not be found in OEIS, the question arises if this sequence is something very special or simply wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. Each number in the sequence is actually the sum of an infinite series, the infinite series' take a similar form, so I'm investigating whether their sums (which are the terms in the sequence) follow a predictable sequence.

Comment: @flinty, I did a fit as you suggested and I got a nice plot. Now how do I use that to predict the next terms of the sequence? Your reply would be highly appreciated flinty. Thanks.

Comment: @Thando well you have the fitted equation in the `fit` variable, so `fit /. x->(1+Length[data])` will evaluate it for the next term after the last one.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. One last question flinty, how do I get the coefficients of the cubic equation that fits the data ?